# How to change the limits and divisions of the axes of each facet using ggplot2? Dealing with "error in x$clone() attempt to apply non-function"

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, facet, facet-wrap

I am creating a graph divided into facets. Some of these facets need to be on a smaller scale for better viewing. I have already applied several tricks to achieve this. However, I need to change the limits and divisions of the axes of some facets.

Calling the necessary packages, creating the database and making the plot

```
devtools::install_github("zeehio/facetscales")
library(ggplot2)
library(facetscales)

#Constructing data frame
Source <- c(rep("Water", 12), rep("Oil", 12))
Range <- rep((c(rep("First", 4), rep("Second", 8))),2)
Xaxis <- c(0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40,
           0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40)
Yaxis <- c(0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40,
           0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40)

DF <- data.frame(Source, Range, Xaxis, Yaxis)
      
#plot
p <- ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Xaxis, y = Yaxis)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ x) +
  geom_point()
```

I initially used `facet_wrap` with `scales = "free"`, but what I really want is to be able to modify the limits and divisions of the x-axis of the facets in the `"First"` row.

```
#plot using facet wrap
p + facet_wrap(Range~Source,
               scales = "free") +
  ggtitle("Using facet_wrap")
```

[image]

So I chose to use the `facetscales` package and followed [this (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54074323/7769755) and [this (2)](https://rdrr.io/github/zeehio/facetscales/man/facet_grid_sc.html) examples

```
#axis specifications
scale_x <- list(
  "First" = scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 10), breaks = c(0, 2, 10)),
  "Second"= scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 40), breaks = c(0, 5, 40))
)

#plot using facet grid and the facetscales package
p + facet_grid_sc(rows = vars(Range),
                  cols = vars (Source),
                  scales = list(x = scale_x)) +
  ggtitle("Using facet_grid_sc")
```

When trying to make the graph with the specifications that I need appears:

```
error in x$clone() attempt to apply non-function
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: its hard to say, maybe `facetscales` depends on an older version of the `ggplot2` package?
`ggplot2::Scale` is the only `ggproto` object that has a `$clone()` method. If `facetscales` replaces the `scales` object with something that doesn't have a `$clone()` method then thats the issue.

Comment: Also, I checked, it does have a `$clone()` method, so this may just be a bug. Maybe post about it on the developer's github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the reason it doesn't work,

in `facet_grid` the `scales` parameter was used to indicate if each panel would have similar or different scales with `c("free","free_x","free_y")`. But having `free_x` on `facet_grid` is only free in the horizontal direction, and all vertical groupings have the same scale range.

When specifying `facet_grid_sc`, the `scales` parameter is used to distinguish how each scale will be rendered, specifically `scales = list(x = scale_x)` where `scale_x` matches `cols = vars(Range)`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(facetscales)

#Constructing data frame
Source <- c(rep("Water", 12), rep("Oil", 12))
Range <- rep((c(rep("First", 4), rep("Second", 8))),2)
Xaxis <- c(0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40,
           0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40)
Yaxis <- c(0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40,
           0,1,2,5,0,1,2,5,10,20,30,40)

DF <- data.frame(Source, Range, Xaxis, Yaxis)

p <- ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Xaxis, y = Yaxis)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ x) +
  geom_point()

#old plot without facet_grid_sc
p + facet_grid(rows = vars(Range),
               cols = vars (Source))
```

[image]

You see how if you facet by `Range` on rows, they are split vertically instead of horizontality? I dont think `facet_grid_sc` supports a `free_x` while also specifiying the x element of `scales`

```r
scale_x <- list(
  First = scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 10), breaks = c(0, 2, 10)),
  Second= scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 40), breaks = c(0, 5, 40))
)

#new plot where scale_x matches cols argument
p + facet_grid_sc(cols = vars(Range),
                  rows = vars (Source),
                  scales = list(x = scale_x))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

---

### EDIT

It should be noted that `facet_grid_sc` is probably more useful if you want to control the range or labels of each panel cols/rows individually. Using `scales = "free_x"` in `facet_grid` is actually pretty sufficient in this example.

```r
p + facet_grid(cols = vars(Range),
               rows = vars (Source),
               scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>