# Expand axis dates to a full month in each facet

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, axis

I am plotting router statistics (collected from [merlin speed monitoring tool](https://github.com/jackyaz/spdMerlin)).

The graphs are faceted by year-month, and I want each month's x axis to expand to the entire month, even when I only have part of a months data.

In the example below, the data for January 2022 is incomplete (just 6 hours or
so of data).

The code I have tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
X.df <- read.csv(url("https://pastebin.com/raw/sGAzEDe6")) %>%
   mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date, origin="1970-01-01")) 

ggplot(X.df , aes(date, Download, colour = Download)) +
  geom_line()+
facet_wrap(~ month,  scale="free_x",  ncol = 1) +
    scale_colour_gradient(low="red",high="green", limits=c(0.0, 50), oob = squish) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%d/%m", breaks = "7 day", minor_breaks = "1 day") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 60))
```

[image: graph of router speeds]

Again, I want the range of the x axis in each facet to cover the entire month. Thus, I want the X axis for the 2021-12 facet to run from 1st Dec 2021 to 31st Dec 2021, and the X axis for the 2022-01 facet to run from 1st Jan 2022 to 31st Jan 2022.

Is there some way of forcing this within ggplot2?

An additional, smaller self-contained example to try your code on:

```
X.df <- tribble(
  ~date, ~month, ~Download,
"2021-12-01T00:30:36Z","2021-12",20.13,
"2021-12-07T06:30:31Z","2021-12",38.95,
"2021-12-14T08:00:31Z","2021-12",38.44,
"2021-12-21T09:30:29Z","2021-12",28.57,
"2021-12-28T16:00:31Z","2021-12",30.78,
"2021-12-31T13:00:28Z","2021-12",55.45,
"2022-01-01T00:00:28Z","2022-1",55.44,
"2022-01-01T02:30:29Z","2022-1",55.63,
"2022-01-01T03:00:29Z","2022-1",55.75,
"2022-01-01T05:00:29Z","2022-1",55.8,
"2022-01-07T03:00:29Z","2022-1",53.6,
"2022-01-07T05:00:29Z","2022-1",51.8
)
```

As always, thanks in advance. Pete

Comment: If I understand the question, just remove `scale="free_x"`?

Comment: Also, use `date_breaks`, not `breaks`.

Comment: Rui - that doesn't work - it scales the X axis for the whole of the data set, so the X axis runs from 1st Dec to 1st Jan, not 1st Jan to the 31st Jan for the lower graph.

Comment: Hi @PJP! Please make your question self-contained, i.e. create an easily copy-paste-able _minimal_ data in the actual question, instead of relying on a link that may become obsolete at any time. This will increase the value of your post to future visitors. Three-four dates per "year-month" should be enough to illustrate your issue. Also. the desired output of plots may be tricky to describe in words and often results in futile guesses, like below. Thus, feel free to add a simple drawing that shows the desired result. Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 change axis limits for each individual facet panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51735481/ggplot2-change-axis-limits-for-each-individual-facet-panel)

Comment: @Henrik - is it OK that I added the self contained example as above as an edit ?

Comment: @PJP Nice, thanks a lot! I made some small edits - I hope you find them OK. Cheers

Comment: Regarding my removal of "EDIT", please refer to this post: [Should "Edit:" in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged); removal of "answer" in question: [When is it cool to summarize answers in question edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336441/when-is-it-cool-to-summarize-answers-in-question-edit)

Comment: @DanAdams - Hi Dan - I had seen that post on SO, but it didn't do what I required (partly because it would required pre-programming the x axis for each month of the year).  The accepted answer does the job brilliantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updat II: Removed prior versions:

1. In your database there is only one january 2022 date
2. in the dataframe we complete the dates of januare of 2022 using `complete` from `tidyr` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
X.df %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% 
  group_by(month(date)) %>% 
  complete(date = seq(min(date), max(ceiling_date(date, unit = "month") - ddays(1)), by = 'day')) %>%
  fill(month) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, Download, colour = Download)) +
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~ month,  scale="free_x",  ncol = 1) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="red",high="green", limits=c(0.0, 50), oob = squish) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels =  "%d/%m", expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 60))
```

[image]

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: @PJP This should be the accepted answer. But I would substitute `geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = 'gam', formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"))` for `geom_line`.

Comment: @TarJae - Excellent - that does the job.  Thank you.

Can you explain why the group_by is necessary (I played around with your code and it doesn't work without the  group_by).

Comment: `group_by` refers  to `complete`. Without `group_by` the whole year 2022 will be completed. Maybe you should add `ungroup()` after `complete`. :-)