# Custom y axis breaks of facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I have created a faceted plot with `facet_wrap`, and I would like to **change the breaks of y axis** of all facets.

This is my **current plot**:

```
ggplot( mtcars , aes(x=mpg, y=wt, color=as.factor(cyl) )) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  facet_wrap(~cyl,scales = "free_y") +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

This is my **desired y axis breaks**:

```
p = ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  theme_classic()
ymax <- ceiling(max(mtcars$wt))
p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, ymax), expand = c(0, 0)) + expand_limits(y = ymax)
```

[image]

Comment: The desired example doesn't seem to be related to `mtcars`. What is `df$len`?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected this.

Comment: What is then wrong?  `p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, ymax), expand = c(0, 0)) + expand_limits(y = ymax)` produces a `0-6` y-scale.

Comment: I want to create different y axis breaks to different facet, eg: `0-4` in `facet 4`, `0-4` in `facet 6` and `0-6` in `facet 8`.

Comment: perhaps have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54074323/13513328

Comment: Nice, I will hava  a try!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a 'rule' for the y-axis breaks/limits you can provide a function to these arguments of the scale, which will evaluate that function for every facet. Note that the `limits` function gets the 'natural' data limits as argument, whereas the `breaks` function gets the expanded limits as argument.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot( mtcars , aes(x=mpg, y=wt, color=as.factor(cyl) )) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  facet_wrap(~cyl,scales = "free_y") +
  theme(legend.position="none")

p + scale_y_continuous(
  limits = ~ c(min(.x), ceiling(max(.x))),
  breaks = ~ .x[2],
  expand = c(0, 0)
)
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you need to tweak the y-axis of every panel, you might find `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales()` useful. Disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x.

```r
p + ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(y = list(
  cyl == 4 ~ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA)),
  cyl == 6 ~ scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(2.9, 3, 3.1)),
  cyl == 8 ~ scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse")
))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, you haven't give any information about 'df'. so I can't run the code in the 2rd section.(`ymax <- ceiling(max(df$len))`)

In general, to change the breaks of y axis, you could use `scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(), labels = c(), limits = (), ...)`. And use `facet_wrap(~var)` to plot facet.

Please supply more information about 'df'.

Comment: Yes, the question is how to apply different y axis breaks to different facet?