# How to specify individual yaxis limits and breaks for a two facet grid plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, ggh4x

I want to specify individual y-axis for each panel of the facet_grid. I followed the example [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73006975/7616699) using ggh4x package. I get an error that says `Error in rlang::eval_tidy(x, layout) : object '3' not found` Any suggestions?

```
mtcars$gear <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

ggplot(mtcars , aes(x=mpg, y=wt, color=as.factor(cyl) )) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  facet_grid(gear~cyl,scales = "free_y") +
  theme(legend.position="none") + 
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(y = list(
  gear == `3` ~ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6), breaks = seq(0, 5, 2.5)),
  gear == `4` ~ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 7), breaks = seq(0, 5,3)),
  gear == `5` ~ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 5), breaks = seq(0, 5, 1))
))
```

Comment: Remove the backticks from around the numbers and it works just fine.

Comment: @AllanCameron My original data has facors with names like "A. Cameron". If I remove the backtick it doesn't work. I'm looking for a general solution that fits all

Comment: Nvm..I need to use double quotes for names "". Figures it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
mtcars$gear <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

ggplot(mtcars , aes(x=mpg, y=wt, color=as.factor(cyl) )) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  facet_grid(gear~cyl,scales = "free_y") +
  theme(legend.position="none") + 
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(y = list(
  gear == "3" ~ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6), breaks = seq(0, 5, 2.5)),
  gear == "4" ~ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 7), breaks = seq(0, 5,3)),
  gear == "5" ~ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 5), breaks = seq(0, 5, 1))
))
```

[image]